# Automatically run this VBA macro everyday at a given time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run this VBA macro everyday. The code runs fine manually but won't activate at that time that is stated in the code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Set the time to run the macro
    Dim runTime As Date
    runTime = TimeValue("10:46:00") ' Change the time to the desired run time
    
    ' Calculate the time until the next run
    Dim timeUntilRun As Date
    timeUntilRun = Date + runTime - Now
    
    ' Schedule the macro to run at the specified time
    Application.OnTime TimeValue(runTime), "UploadDataToFile"
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub UploadDataToFile()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    'Get today's date
    Dim currentDate As Date
    currentDate = Date
   
    'Get the last row of data in column B
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   
    'Loop through each row in the data range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B").Value < currentDate Then
            'If the date in column B is less than today's date, delete the entire row
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
   
    'Set the file name based on the current date
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Format(currentDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "TorqueValues.xlsx"
   
    'Set the file path for saving
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "C:\Users\PROD\Documents\" & fileName
    
    'Copy the data to a new workbook
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
   
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy newWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Cells
   
    'Save the new workbook at the specified file path with the XLSX file format
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    newWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filePath, FileFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   
    newWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    'Code execution will resume here if no errors occur
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    'Handle the error
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
    'Optionally, log the error or perform any necessary cleanup
    
    'Code execution will resume here after handling the error
End Sub
```

I changed the time to 10:46 to see if it would run by itself but it didn't. The actual time is supposed to be 8pm. I also tried using task scheduler and vbs script, but I couldn't get that to work either so I opted to try to figure this method out first. In task scheduler, the vbs script worked, but the task didn't automate itself when I ran it, so similar problem.

Comment: `Date + TimeValue("10:46:00")` would be what you'd want to pass to `OnTime` as the scheduled run time.   8PM would be `Date + (20/24)` (1 day = 24 hours so 8pm is 20/24 of a day)